# ERC 1155 Token Standard

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, erc20, erc721, erc1155

I have read about ERC 1155 that how it can be used to mint both **fungible(ERC20)** and **non-fungible(ERC721)** tokens. So my question is:

1. Fungible tokens that we mint using **ERC1155** will have exact **same functions** as a token minted from **ERC20** contract will have or more functions can be added in it from **ERC721** standard?
2. I guess what I mean is that can functions of **ERC20** and **ERC721** be mixed to create kind of a semi fungable token?

Answer (score 1):

**ERC 1155 can be used to create semi-fungible tokens.**

You can see this by checking the ERC 1155 docs: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155

The **Simple Summary** states: "A standard interface for contracts that manage multiple token types. A single deployed contract may include any combination of fungible tokens, non-fungible tokens **or other configurations (e.g. semi-fungible tokens)**."

Note: It would have been better to post this question on the [Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply I somehow missed  "(e.g. semi-fungible tokens)" when I read it and also for mentioning better platform for Ethereum based questions.

Answer (score 1):

`ERC1155` supports both `ERC20` and `ERC721`. It is usually used in game applications.

In gaming, gold, iron, or gem are exchanged by the game players so those should support `ERC20`. They are fungible because they are interchangeable.
But swords, spaceships, knights, or shields are implemented as `ERC721`. There can be many of them, so they are called collections but since they are not interchanged they are implemented as `ERC721`.

It would cost too much to run two different smart contracts. There would be alot of transactions between those two contracts. That is why `ERC1155` is created